# Installing Kaldi using Cygwin, error on zlib

Tags: linux, cygwin, package, zlib, kaldi

I am trying to install kaldi on a windows computer using cygwin.
When I run ./tools/check_dependencies.sh (as requested in the INSTALL file)
I get "zlib is not installed", so I go to the cygwin package list and try to install.
The thing is - there is no "zlib" per say [see snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbnxL.png)
there are all kinds of packages but their execution name is not "zlib" (except one which is irrelevant), it's always something-zlib-somthing.

And so I end up getting the same message even after I install them.
The code in check_dependencies.sh that does that is:

if ! echo "#include " | $CXX -E - >&/dev/null; then
  echo "$0: zlib is not installed."
  add_packages zlib-devel zlib1g-dev zlib-devel
fi

I understood there is no (relevant) way of installing zlib directly with cygwin - so that's a dead end.

Anyway I tried to make it work but no success - your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: as the `zlib-devel` is installed, the test on `check_dependencies.sh` is likely wrong; and you need to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Kaldi in cygwin is originally a bad idea. Its kind of supported but you will have many problems here and there. Simply install Linux either on a separate server or in a virtual machine.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I did it with Ubuntu and got it to work.